# Facebook Dynamic Open Graph Meta Data

Tags: facebook, metadata

I want to dynamically add content to the facebook open graph meta data. Here's my code, but the content field shows up blank on page load.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{exp:channel:entries}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}">
```

I tried the other solutions and SEO Lite has very bad documentation so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag has zero parameters, meaning you have little control over what's being loaded unless it is detecting it from the URL. I'm also guessing it's possible this Channel Entries loop lives inside of another one, which won't work. You'll have to provide significantly more information for us to give you a real answer...

But without more details, I'm going to guess you have a nested Channel Entries loop. Use an [embed](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/embedding.html) if you need to pull a different channel entry title in, or just use the `{title}` tag if it's already in a loop.

If it isn't nested and you're not sure what's going on, try hard coding an `entry_id` and test a few parameters to see if you get an output. Try these parameters on the tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id='1' dynamic='no' limit='1'}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Use a known `entry_id` that has a status of **open**. See if that gets you somewhere.

Comment: Tried adding in that tag with no result. I'm running expression engine 2 and there's not much of documentation on how to use channel:entries lest you already know what you are doing (spoiler alert: I don't).

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning I'm testing this on localhost and using inspect element to see the output of the og:title content.

Comment: Do you have any channels created? Are you able to output channel entry data elsewhere?

Comment: And if you do have a channel created, make sure it is assigned a **Status Group**. If you don't the channel entries act a little funky because they don't have any standard status.